# Fictional AB-Type flip-flop

Tags: control-engineering

I'm doing an optional review sheet before a test and I'm stuck on this one problem. I really don't know what it's asking. Can someone help lead me in the right way? Thank you[image]

Comment: Have you learned how to draw Karnaugh maps and derive a sum-of-products equation from that? Draw a simple Karnaugh map with A, B and Q as the input variables.